# What kind of structure is it?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> I’m glad this programme is about singing because I
> love it and what I lack in ability, I make up for in enthusiasm!

It's taken from [the BBC podcast](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/oromo/features/6-minute-english/ep-210218)

I understood the meaning with the help of an English to Turkish text translator but I don't understand the structure and have never seen a sentence like this before. Is it correct (in spoken language, I'm not asking for formal language) ?

Comment: "What I lack in X I make up for in Y" is a fairly standard expression, meaning "I may not  be very good at (the activity in question), but I'm very keen."

Comment: The text is ambiguous. Is the subject saying she loves *the programme,* or she loves *singing*? But don't be thrown by the two adverbial qualifiers ***in ability*** and ***in enthusiasm*** that are being deliberately juxtaposed / contrasted for effect. Consider a simpler version with no such qualifiers: ***What I want, I get***.

Comment: ...which could be "qualified" in much the same way as ***What I wanted yesterday, I get tomorrow*** (good things often arrive too late for me to appreciate them. cf *It's always jam yesterday and jam tomorrow, but never jam today*).